# Code execution exploit Cortex M4

Tags: arm, exploit, cortex-m

For testing the MPU and playing around with exploits, I want to execute code from a local buffer running on my STM32F4 dev board.

```
int main(void)
{
  uint16_t func[] = { 0x0301f103, 0x0301f103, 0x0301f103 };
  MPU->CTRL = 0;
  unsigned int address = (void*)&func+1;
  asm volatile(
    "mov r4,%0\n"
    "ldr pc, [r4]\n"
    :    
    : "r"(address)    
  ); 
  while(1);
}
```

In main, I first turn of the MPU. In func my instructions are stored. In the ASM part I load the address (0x2001ffe8 +1 for thumb) into the program counter register. When stepping through the code with GDB, in R4 the correct value is stored and then transfered to PC register. But then I will end up in the HardFault Handler.

Edit:
The stack looks like this:

```
0x2001ffe8: 0x0301f103  0x0301f103  0x0301f103  0x2001ffe9
```

The instructions are correct in the memory. Definitive Guide to Cortex says region 0x20000000–0x3FFFFFFF is the SRAM and "this region is  executable, 
so you can copy program code here and execute it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning 32 bit values to a 16 bit array.

Your instructions dont terminate, they continue on to run into whatever is found in ram, so that will crash.

You are not loading the address to the array into the program counter you are loading the first item in the array into the program counter, this will crash, you created a level of indirection.

Look at the BX instruction for this rather than ldr pc

You did not declare the array as static, so the array can be optimized out as dead and unused, so this can cause it to crash.

The compiler should also complain that you are assigning a void* to an unsigned variable, so a typecast is wanted there.

As a habit I recommend address|=1 rather than +=1, in this case either will function.

Comment: Recommend using intptr_t from stdint.h for an integral type that's guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer (provided you're using >=C99, which really everyone should be in 2018!) rather than unsigned int.